# Evaluate logic expression given as a string in PHP

Tags: php, boolean-logic

I have an object which has a state property, for example *state = 'state4'* or *state = 'state2'*.

Now I also have an array of all available states that the state property can get, *state1* to *state8* (**note: the states are not named stateN. They have eight different names, like payment or canceled. I just put stateN to describe the problem**).

In addition to that, I have a logical expression like *$expression = !state1||state4&&(!state2||state5)* for example. This is the code for the above description:

```
$state = 'state4';
$expression = '!state1||state4&&(!state2||state5)';
```

Now I want to check if the logical expression is true or false. In the above case, it's true. In the following case it would be false:

```
$state = 'state1';
$expression = state4&&!state2||(!state1||state7);
```

How could this be solved in an elegant way?

Comment: I solved this problem some years ago with eval() for my own application. But to make the code more portable I'm rebuilding it in a hierarchical database table, so that the database can evaluate the logical boolean expression for me, instead of PHP. But that is outside of the 'in PHP' requirement you set out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Initialize
$state = 'state4';
$expression = '!state1||state4&&(!state2||state5)';

//Adapt to your needs
$pattern='/state\d/';

//Replace
$e=str_replace($state,'true',$expression);
while (preg_match_all($pattern,$e,$matches)
   $e=str_replace($matches[0],'false',$e);

//Eval
eval("\$result=$e;");
echo $result;
```

**Edit:**

Your update to the OQ necessitates some minor work:

```
//Initialize
$state = 'payed';
$expression = '!payed||cancelled&&(!whatever||shipped)';

//Adapt to your needs
$possiblestates=array(
   'payed',
   'cancelled',
   'shipped',
   'whatever'
);

//Replace
$e=str_replace($state,'true',$expression);
$e=str_replace($possiblestates,'false',$e);

//Eval
eval("\$result=$e;");
echo $result;
```

**Edit 2**

There has been concern about `eval` and PHP injection in the comments: The expression and the replacements are completly controlled by the application, no user input involved. As long as this holds, `eval` is safe.

Comment: Very risky using `eval`, leaves you open to PHP injections

Comment: @Znarkus No chance of PHP injection: The `eval`'ed expression is completly controlled by the site owner: `$expression = '!state1||state4&&(!state2||state5)';` - no user input there!

Answer (score 1):

I am using ExpressionLanguage, but there are few different solutions

1. ExpressionLanguage Symfony Component - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

   - cons - weird array syntax - array['key']. array.key works only for objects
   - cons - generate notice for array['key'] when key is not defined
   - pros - stable and well maintainer
2. https://github.com/mossadal/math-parser
3. https://github.com/optimistex/math-expression

**Please remember that eval is NOT an option, under NO circumstances.** We don't live an a static world. Any software always grows and evolves. What was once considered a safe input an one point may turn completely unsafe and uncontrolled.

Comment: If "eval is NOT an option, under NO circumstances" were true, then the PHP developers would have removed `eval` long ago - the riskiy part is using **user input** in eval. This does not happen here, as everything in the `eval`is in the complete control of the site owner. It is also quite a leap of faith to assume, that a constant string might magically become "completely unsafe and uncontrolled" at some point in the future.

Comment: It should be noted, that @YourCommonSense used his rep points to change the original answer's "If you can change syntax - you could use "php style syntax" and eval" into "Please remember that eval is NOT an option, under NO circumstances.", has already given a 500 Bounty to the NOT accepted answer and does so again right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a case which can be solved if you model each of your expressions as a **rooted [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG)**.

I assumed **acyclic** since your ultimate aim is to find the result of boolean algebra operations (if cycling occur in any of graph, then it'd be nonsense I think).

However, even if your graph structure—meaningfully—can be cyclic then your target search term will be **cyclic graph**, and it should still have a solution.

```
$expression = '!state1||state4&&(!state2||state5)';
```

And you have one root with two sub_DAGs in your example.

```
EXPRESSION as a Rooted DAG:

          EXPRESSION
              |
             AND
        ___/     \___
      OR             OR
     /  \           /  \
! S_1    S_4     ! S_2  S5
```

Your **adjacency list** is:

```
expression_adj_list = [
    expression => [ subExp_1, subExp_2 ] ,
    subExp_1 => [ ! S_1, S_4 ],
    subExp_2 => [ ! S_2, S5 ]
]
```

Now you can walk through this graph by [BFS (breadth-first search algorithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS (depth-first search algorithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or your custom, adjusted algorithm.

Of course you can just visit the adjacency list with keys and values as many times as you need if this suits and is easier for you.

You'll need a **lookup table** to teach your algorithm that. For example,

- S2 && S5 = 1,
- S1 or S4 = 0,
- S3 && S7 = -1 (to throw an exception maybe)

After all, the algorithm below can solve your expression's result.

```
$adj_list = convert_expression_to_adj_list();
// can also be assigned by a function.
// root is the only node which has no incoming-edge in $adj_list.
$root = 'EXPRESSION';
q[] = $root; //queue to have expression & subexpressions
$results = [];
while ( ! empty(q)) {
    $current = array_shift($q);
    if ( ! in_array($current, $results)) {
        if (isset($adj_list[$current])) { // if has children (sub/expression)
            $children = $adj_list[$current];
            // true if all children are states. false if any child is subexpression.
            $bool = is_calculateable($children);
            if ($bool) {
                $results[$current] = calc($children);
            }
            else {
                array_unshift($q, $current);
            }
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                if (is_subexpresssion($child) && ! in_array($child, $results)) {
                    array_unshift($q, $child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return $results[$root];
```

This approach has a great advantage also: if you save the results of the expressions in your database, if an expression is a child of the root expression then you won't need to recalculate it, just use the result from the database for the child subexpressions. In this way, you always have a two-level depth DAG (root and its children).